# get data attribute from select with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Thank you in advance for your help.  This one is kicking my butt.  I've found a couple of similar questions here, tried their suggestions, but it's still not working.

What I'm trying to do is get the data attributes from the select tag, and the value of the selected option and pass those through an AJAX request.

Console shows "groupid undefined" and the groupId and menuId variables don't get passed.

And I know I should just quit being stubborn and just put the data-groupid and menuid in the "options" and use the $(this).find(':selected').data('menuid') route...

HTML:

```
<select id="menuArray" class="menuPermission" data-groupid="2" data-menuid="9">
 <option>-</option>
 <option value="R">R</option>
 <option value="W">W</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(".menuPermission").change(function(){
    //console.log("groupid"+$(this).data('groupid'))
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "popup.php",
        data: {
            action:"updateAdminAccess", 
            groupId:$(this).data("groupid"), 
            access:$(this).val(), 
            menuId:$(this).data("menuid")}
    });
})
```

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RstqF/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `$(this)` in the `$.ajax()` object and it is therefore returning `$.ajax()`.

Try this (no pun intended):

```
$(".menuPermission").change(function(){
    var obj = this;
    //console.log("groupid"+$(this).data('groupid'))
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "popup.php",
        data: {
            action:"updateAdminAccess", 
            groupId:$(obj).data("groupid"), 
            access:$(obj).val(), 
            menuId:$(obj).data("menuid")}
    });
})
```

Comment: Uhm, no! There's no change of scope there!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.attr('attribute-name')
```

to get certain attribute value

```
$(".menuPermission").change(function(){
        var groupId = $(this).attr('data-groupid');
        var menuId  = $(this).attr('data-menuid');
        var optionVal   = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "popup.php",
            data: {
                action:"updateAdminAccess", 
                groupId:groupId, 
                access:optionVal, 
                menuId:menuId}
        });
    })
```